# How to create an empty SpatialLinesDataFrame in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp, r-sf

I need to create and SpatialLinesDataFrame with a predefined structure (9 fields). I'm performing a function over a list of shp which I want to append to this empty spatiallinesdataframe.

I already know how to save each shp within a folder and then merge all, but now, I'd like to merge all the sph within the iteration to avoid save and reread steps.

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer as you haven't provided any examples or code of what you're trying to achieve. At the moment your question isn't very clear, what do you mean by 'merge all the sph within the iteration'? - data merge or spatial merge? Is this even relevant to the question of creating an empty SPLDF object?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307370/how-to-create-and-empty-spatiallinesdataframe